# Track Bandwidth Usage using PHP?

Tags: php, tracking

I want to track the bandwidth that a file has consumed. the files are not served by a php system , ( example : download.php?file=xyz.zip) .. they are direct links.

one method I am trying to do is :
parsing the server logs and detect the bandwidth , but it has turned out to be more complex than I thought ..

please suggest me some ways to do the same ..

thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not install something like:

- Awstats
- Webalizer
- Analog

to parse your log files.

Comment: Hi, I have used Awstats in the past , its really nice. but does it offer any API so that I can use the data ?

Answer (score 1):

Analog has a [computer readable output](http://analog.cx/docs/compout.html) mode. You could run files through Analog and then parse the files it generates to get the info you need.